# Attempting to pull not submitted/missing time sheets

Tags: sql

I have a view set up for me to pull data from. If an employee creates a time sheet but doesn't submit it, I am able to capture the data. If the employee doesn't create a time sheet then I am unable to pull and  report that they haven't submitted it. In the desired outcome, I would like to be able to capture pay periods that are missing.

```
    SELECT
   LOGON_CODE, PERIOD, STATUS, 
   START_DT, END_DT
   FROM IGDBA.V_OI_TIME_CHARGES TC
   JOIN IGDBAP.OIG_EMPLOYEES E ON E.LOGON_CD = TC.LOGON_CODE
WHERE
    TRUNC (TC.START_DT) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('09/27/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('05/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')
    AND TC.STATUS NOT IN('S','A')
    AND E.VALID_FLG = 'Y'
    AND LOGON_CODE IN ('JohnDoe','JaneDoe')
    GROUP BY LOGON_CODE, PERIOD, STATUS,START_DT, END_DT
```

[image: View]

This is the outcome.

[image: Outcome]

This is the desired outcome.

[image: Desired Outcome]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT
   LOGON_CODE, PERIOD, STATUS, 
   START_DT, END_DT
   FROM IGDBAP.OIG_EMPLOYEES E 
   LEFT JOIN IGDBA.V_OI_TIME_CHARGES TC ON E.LOGON_CD = TC.LOGON_CODE
   WHERE
    TRUNC (TC.START_DT) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('09/27/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('05/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')
    AND TC.STATUS NOT IN('S','A')
    AND E.VALID_FLG = 'Y'
    AND LOGON_CODE IN ('JohnDoe','JaneDoe')
    AND (TC.LOGON_CODE IS NULL OR TC.LOGON_CODE IN ('R','N'))
    GROUP BY LOGON_CODE, PERIOD, STATUS,START_DT, END_DT
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` is probably the solution to your problem.  But you need to be careful that the all filtering on the *second* table is in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT LOGON_CODE, PERIOD, STATUS, START_DT, END_DT
FROM IGDBA.V_OI_TIME_CHARGES TC JOIN
     IGDBAP.OIG_EMPLOYEES E
     ON E.LOGON_CD = TC.LOGON_CODE AND
        E.VALID_FLG = 'Y'
WHERE TRUNC(TC.START_DT) BETWEEN DATE '2019-09-27 AND DATE '2020-05-01' AND
      TC.STATUS NOT IN ('S','A')
      TC.LOGON_CODE IN ('JohnDoe', 'JaneDoe');
```

I don't think the `GROUP BY` is necessary so I removed it.